# How to return a div plus an array map on render method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have just followed the Tic Tac Toe Tutorial on ReactJS (from this information you can guess how newbie I am to ReactJS) and I'm trying to write a Sudoku game based on it.

I have created 3 components: `Game`, `Board` and `Cell`.

States are stored on `Game` and passed down to `Board`, and then down to `Cell`.

I want to have as a result a set of 9 `div` which class is equal to `game-row` and inside each one a set of 9 `div` with `className="cell"`.

I could successfully return the `Cell` elements by mapping rows and then mapping cell but don't know how to put each row inside a `div className="gamerow"`.

Should I create a Row component or is there any other/better way?

*p.s.: for the sake of simplicity on result and console I have written the code snippet with 3 rows and 3 cells each.*

```js
const Cell = ({cellData}) => {
  return ( 
    <div className="cell">
      { cellData.key }
    </div>
   );
}

const Board = ({ rows }) => {
  console.log(rows);
  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((row) => {
        return row.cells.map((cell) => {
          return <Cell cellData={cell}></Cell>;
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let emptyBoard = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
      emptyBoard.push({
        rowNumber: row,
        cells: []
      })
      for (let col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        emptyBoard[row].cells.push({
          key: 'r'+row.toString()+'c'+col.toString(),
          row: row,
          col: col
        });
      }
    }
    this.state = {
      board:emptyBoard,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="board-container">
          <Board rows={this.state.board} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.board-row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.cell {
    background: #faf;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Look into CSS grid or flexbox for layout - it will be more modern, robust, and forward compatible than tables and floats.  Can you also maybe clarify your question?  Are you trying to wrap every 3 cells in an extra div for the row?  And if so, what is the purpose?  If it's layout - use CSS; no need for extra HTML unless it's structurally important.

Comment: Hi @TomPietrosanti. The purpose for now is layout. I want to draw the cells of each row in a different row. Is there a way to do that without wrapping the cells inside a `row` div?

Comment: Definitely.  Start by looking into CSS Grid.  Alternately you could use Flexbox with a max-width and wrap.  https://gridbyexample.com/ is a good place to start with Grid.